# After parsing JSON file data, add comments to result XML

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Due to flattening the parsed JSON data, I need to add some comments to serve as titles and code line separators to have a better overview of the XML result. The text in the comment fields can either come from the high-level keys from JSON or just added manually when creating the comments.

I have tried to add the standard way of creating comments in XSL, but due to the templates I use matches several nodes, the result is an iteration where the comments appear on top of every transformed element.

If recommended the comments can also be added through separate template(s).

You find the code here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ3X/4

Below is a extractions of the code:

**JSON data:**

```
<data>

{
  "ix_hidden": [
    {
    "CompanyName": "Link Inc",
    "OrganisationNumber": "123"
    }
  ],

  "other": [
    {
      "SomethingElse": "Juice"
    }
  ]

}

</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:rot="http://www.example.com/2"
  >

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
  <report>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
  </report>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Flatten data, exlude high-level key names-->

<xsl:template match="*[@key and not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>

<!-- Add comments equal as the key values from parsed JSON-->

<!-- Add comment for "ix_hidden" -->
<xsl:comment>Group:ix_hidden</xsl:comment>

<!-- Add comment for "other" -->
<xsl:comment>Group:other</xsl:comment>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:rot="http://www.example.com/2">
   <CompanyName>Link Inc</CompanyName>
   <!--Group:ix_hidden-->
   <!--Group:other-->
   <OrganisationNumber>123</OrganisationNumber>
   <!--Group:ix_hidden-->
   <!--Group:other-->
   <SomethingElse>Juice</SomethingElse>
   <!--Group:ix_hidden-->
   <!--Group:other-->
</report>
```

**Wanted result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:rot="http://www.example.com/2">
   <!--Group:ix_hidden-->
   <CompanyName>Link Inc</CompanyName>
   <OrganisationNumber>123</OrganisationNumber>
   <!--Group:other-->
   <SomethingElse>Juice</SomethingElse>
</report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like adding the comments with separate templates works fine.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ3X/5

Using this XSL will get the comments in place. Note that the comment values are hardcoded and not fetched from the parsing of JSON. The preferred solution would be to reuse the JSON key values as comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  >

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
  <report>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
  </report>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Flatten data, exlude high-level key names-->

<xsl:template match="*[@key and not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add comments equal as the key values from parsed JSON-->

<xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'ix_hidden']">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:comment>ix_hidden</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'other']">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:comment>certifications</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Match on the arrays and output the comment, then apply templates:

```
<!-- Add comments equal as the key values from parsed JSON-->

<xsl:template match="*:map/*:array[@key]">
  <xsl:comment expand-text="yes">Group:{@key}</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```